# Ubound in multidimension array with differing lengths?

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, vba

So I have a multidimensional array in Excels VBA. I'm reading a txt file in excel with multiple semicolon delimted lines. each line is read, and split into an array, and added to the multi-D array. Codez:

```
Dim filenum As Integer        'number of next "free file"
Dim splitCols As Variant
Dim counter As Long
Dim brCodes() As Variant
Dim textline As String
Dim lines As Variant
Dim numrows As Long
Dim numcols As Long

numcols = getNumColumns(ActiveSheet.Name)
numrows = getNumRows(ActiveSheet.Name)

counter = 0

filenum = FreeFile()           'find next free filenum

Open FileName For Input As #filenum    'open file for reading    

'codes are put into an array
While Not EOF(filenum)   'process while file has more lines.

    counter = counter + 1

    Line Input #filenum, textline 'grab current line into textline

    splitCols = Split(textline, ";")

    ReDim Preserve brCodes(1 To counter)

    brCodes(counter) = splitCols

Wend



Close #filenum  'close file\
```

now what I'd like is to loop through each array in `brCodes`. I normally use a forloop like -

```
for i = lbound(brCodes,2) to ubound(brCodes,2)
    'process stuff
 next
```

but the arrays in brCodes are different lengths. The lines in the text file have differing number of semi colons. it looks like this:

```
str1;str2;str3;str4;sdtr5
str1;str2;str3;str4;sdtr5;str6;str7
str1;str2;str3;str4
```

so will I have to add an intermediate step to pull out each array into a temp variable and deal with it like that? or does anyone have a way of getting the ubound of a particular "Row" without pulling it out first?

### added

I also tried:

```
For i = LBound(brCodes, 2) To UBound(brCodes, 2)
    For j = LBound(brCodes(i)) To UBound(brCodes(i))
        MsgBox ("")
    Next
Next
```

but I get the same subscript out of range error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UNTESTED**

It's not a multi-dimensional array. It's a one-dimensional array of `Variants`, and each variant holds an array of whatever length. I think your second attempt is close, but it should be like:

```
For i = LBound(brCodes) To UBound(brCodes)
    For j = LBound(brCodes(i)) To UBound(brCodes(i))
        MsgBox ("")
    Next
Next
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I never even thought that would work i just tried because it was one more thing before bashing my head in.. I've been trying all of these ways of doing it with actual 2D arrays, I guess last time I did this it was a legit 2D array so I couldnt figure out why none of those ways worked, and I was making it way too complicated.

Comment: Glad I could help. Good question. It's a confusing situation!